# How to distribute evenly a set of same width boxes inside of a bootstrap fluid container?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How to distribute evenly a set of same width boxes inside of a fluid container?

I have the following:

```
<div class="fluid-container">
  <span>some text</span>
  <span>some text2</span>
  ...
  <span>some textN</span>
</div>
```

I want to achieve this result of nicely even spaced boxes where each pink box containing a given text is always of the same width inside of the blue fluid container:

[image: Desired layout]

I tried to set up boxes inside of it, but then I get them one after each other in the next row, not using the lateral space optimally:

[image: Result with boxes stacking up but not using lateral space]

If I don't use anything in the text (like the span I used), then the fluid container does its trick but the text is not evenly spaced (in this case the yellow boxes are text that is not wrapped with any tag):

[image: Result of fluid container class wrapping a bunch of unwrapped text]

What class/css code should I use to organize and wrap the text so it result in same width boxes? The number of boxes is not known.

Comment: Do you want to to this with `Bootstrap` or without it?

Comment: Have you not read the Bootstrap Documents?....I'm not sure what your equstion actually is.

Comment: Did you make an effort to read the docs? There is no `fluid-container`. Use `row` and `col-*` for columns. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Something like [this?](https://jsfiddle.net/4ynndm3m/1/)

Comment: Thanks jbutler483, that basically it was!

Answer (score 2):

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

> Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that
>   appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size
>   increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as
>   well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">text</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">text</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why you want to use a 'fluid grid' specifically. Unless you don't want it to collapse to a row when on mobile.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">col 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">col 2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col 3</div>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without any framework you can use `Flexbox`

```css
.fluid-container {
  display: flex;
  background: #5B9BD5;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
}
span {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 20px);
  background: #F8CBAD;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  span {
    flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fluid-container">
  <span>some text</span><span>some text2</span><span>some textN</span><span>some text</span><span>some text2</span><span>some textN</span><span>some text</span><span>some text2</span><span>some textN</span><span>some text</span><span>some text2</span><span>some textN</span>
</div>
```